# Create a JSON object updater

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, updates

I'm working with a specific JSON object in javascript that contains multiple non fixed properties (I mean properties that can change in the future).

I've been working in something like:

```
{
  "propertyA": {
    "value": "0",
    "type": "A"
  },
  "propertyB": {
    "childs": {
      "propertyC": {
        "prop": "value",
        "anotherProp": "randomValue"
      }
    },
    "type": "B"
  }
}
```

As you can see, not all properties are the same nor follow a pattern. That is because I'm using it to store some configs. The problem is that if I want to change something in the future, let's say that `"propertyA"` changes to `"propertyA": { "config": "0", type: "A" }`, I cannot change the javascript which reads these properties to read the new ones and forget the old ones, because if I receive an old config and try to access to properties identified by latest config version name, it will break the application.

I was thinking in something like: check JSON properties > verify JSON "version" > update accordingly > save updates > read JSON properties changed with new format

What I tried so far is to add a `"version": "1.0"` field to my JSON, then create an updater to check through all versions. Taking the example given, if the latest version of the JSON is 1.2, then updates `"propertyA"` to version 1.1 and 1.2 after that.

But I face 2 problems with this:

1. If I download a very old JSON (stored 1.0 / latest 5.2), probably it will take too much time to update it if going through all versions until it reaches 5.2 version.
2. The user could have access to the database. This means that he can change the JSON version manually. I know that this is kinda impossible and doing it would break the application, but I want to keep it as secure as I can.

Basically, I want to know how to update between versions of my JSON configs swiftly, no matter how many different versions are between the received config and the latest one (like an acumulative updater or something like that, which updates to the latest version no matter which version is the old one), and without storing the version in the same JSON or in DB, if possible (like determining the version depending which attributes it has).

PS: I'm using Typescript, if it helps to find an easier solution.

Comment: Your 2 problems can easily be mitigated - **1**: don’t change your API very often. If you must, and the conversion takes [more than 3 seconds](https://think.storage.googleapis.com/docs/mobile-page-speed-new-industry-benchmarks.pdf), allow for the conversion to happen in the background (e.g. using a [`WebWorker`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers)) while the user continues to use your site; and **2**: don’t reuse property keys once they’ve been deprecated. If v1.1 changes `value` to `config`, don’t let v4.5 introduce a new property `value`

Comment: The alternative would be to write a utility merge function that takes each json file version, and merge it into a new big file with a property of the version/filename, then the rest of the JSON as a data attribute. Then use a JSON to CSV converter - websites exist to similify this.. Then load the CSV in Excel/Googledocs spreadsheet to compare differences.. http://www.convertcsv.com/json-to-csv.htm

Comment: @MTCoster Of course I will not change my API very often to prevent this behavior. But I like the way you suggested the use of a `WebWorker`, I will take a look into it.

Comment: @JGFMK your suggestion looks a bit hard to implement, but It sounds good with the "merging" option, as it will probably take less time for updating the data. I will take a look into it too and also to how can I "replace" the deprecated property in favor of the new property using the same value or converting it as needed. Thanks :)